How to retrieve RoomType ID from MongoDB Schema from room numbers ID
I want to get Deluxe Room id for example I only can get roomNumbers Id which is "_id": 662be374ac75214a75b8580c as starting point. How can I get "_id": "662be374ac75214a75b8580b" this id Of Room Type so in end I can access the price.
This is my MongoDB schema:
{
    "_id": "662be374ac75214a75b8580b",
    "title": "Deluxe Room",
    "price": 150,
    "maxPeople": 2,
    "desc": "Spacious room with modern amenities.Private bathroom in the accommodation Flat-screen TV",
    "roomNumbers": [
        {
            "number": 105,
            "unavailableDates": [
                "2024-05-15T15:55:58.646Z",
                "2024-05-15T16:10:49.965Z",
                "2024-05-21T23:00:00.000Z",
                "2024-05-22T23:00:00.000Z",
                "2024-05-19T21:54:38.864Z",
                "2024-05-28T23:00:00.000Z",
                "2024-05-29T23:00:00.000Z",
                "2024-05-19T23:14:32.196Z"
            ],
            "_id": "662be374ac75214a75b8580c"
        }
    ]
}

I tried to get room Id "_id": "662be374ac75214a75b8580c" and it works fine. But couldn't get roomtype ID. I'm trying to the Price.

Use a projection with your find: { _id: 1, price: 1 }: https://mongoplayground.net/p/D2UtM_8Ew_c
